# How to use FCM in ionic v1

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm, ionic-v1

I am new in ionic, I want to know how to use FCM in ionic v1 project Please help me. I am using Cordova-plugin-fcm.
At first, i am installing this plugin in my project using this comment
"ionic Cordova plugin add Cordova-plugin-fcm"

```
FCMPlugin.getToken(
function (token) {
    alert('Token: ' + token);
    console.log('Token: ' + token);
},
function (err) {
    alert('error retrieving token: ' + token);
    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
}
```

);

then using this code in my app.js,  $ionicPlatform.ready()

now the error is showing my browser console

```
FCMPlugin is not defined
```

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your plugin which you added and install these plugins by writing following command:

1. **ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm.**
2. **ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.**

Note: Try removing your platforms and hooks if your problem persist and install the above plugin again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question just add this plugin.

Comment: yeah just add these plugins and run the application for android but  for iOS you have to enable Push Notifications from Xcode > Capabilities.

Comment: i get the error as Unable to find command: plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm .

Comment: I solved using this link https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging